# d3 charts unixtime stamp converted to browser local timezone

Tags: javascript, d3.js, timezone-offset

I am working on d3 charts v4 in angular 4,
when I bind data to y-axis I am giving datetime value in unixtimestamp format.
I deployed web application in to two different timezones

The value I have in database is `2018-05-15 01:41:29.853`

when I browse URL in **IST** the chart displays time as `Tue May 15 2018 11:11:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

when I browse URL in **EDT** the chart displays time as `Tue May 15 2018 01:41:29 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

MY CODE SAMPLE FOR D3 YAXIS

```
var y = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataAxis, function (d) {        
         return d.Y; //d.Y values are unixtimestamp Ex: 1526328689853
    }))

var yAxis = d3.axisRight().scale(y).tickValues(y.ticks().concat(y.domain())).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H: %M"));
```

I would like to display values as it is in database no matter where I open,

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which database? Is the value stored in the database based on UTC or EDT? As which datatype is the column defined?

Comment: @SteveR SQL Database, value stored in DB is not based on UTC, the app which inserts data into DB runs on EDT, the datatype of the column is DateTime